# dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid dynamically add multiple grids with add delete row options

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am trying to create dojo dynamic Enhanced grid with Add new row for each grid. The add Button is not able to get the grid index. Please find the code below.I need help in adding a new row for each dynamically generated grids.?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-    8"></meta>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css" />
  <title>Dynamic Data Grid</title>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="dojoroot/dojo    /dojo.js" djConfig:async:true, "parseOnLoad:true">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dojoroot/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
  </script>
  <script>
    require(
      ['dojo/on', 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/domReady!', 'dojo/_base/lang',
        'dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid', 'dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore',
        'dijit/form/Button', 'dojo/_base/array',
        'dojo/dom-construct', 'dojo/on', 'dojo/query'
      ],
      function(on, dom, domReady, lang, EnhancedGrid, ItemFileWriteStore,
        Button, array, domConstruct, on, query) {
        /*set up data store*/
        var data1 = {
          identifier: "id",
          items: []
        };
        var store1 = new ItemFileWriteStore({
          data: data1
        });
        /*set up layout*/
        var layout1 = [
          [{
            'name': 'SL',
            'field': 'id',
            'width': '100px'
          }, {
            'name': 'Column 2',
            'field': 'col2',
            'width': '100px',
            editable: true
          }, {
            'name': 'Column 3',
            'field': 'col3',
            'width': '200px',
            editable: true
          }, {
            'name': 'Column 4',
            'field': 'col4',
            'width': '150px',
            editable: true
          }]
        ];
        /*create a new grid*/
        var grid1 = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
          id: 'grid',
          store: store1,
          structure: layout1,
          rowSelector: '20px',
          "style": "height:  100%; width: 100%"
        });
        dojo
          .place(
            "<div id='sam' style='width: 650px; height: 200px; border: 0px solid silver;''></div>",
            dojo.body());
        grid1.placeAt("sam");
        /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
        grid1.startup();
        dojo.place("<br><br><br>", dojo.body());
        dojo
          .place(
            "<button id='addRow' data-dojo-type='dijit.form.Button'>Add Row</button>",
            dojo.body());
        dojo
          .place(
            "<button id='delRow' data-dojo-type='dijit.form.Button'>Delete Row</button>",
            dojo.body());
        //Add new row
        var button = new Button({
          onClick: function() {
            store1.newItem({
              id: " SL :" + (grid1.rowCount + 1),
              col2: "col2-" + (grid1.rowCount + 1),
              col3: "col3-" + (grid1.rowCount + 1),
              col4: "col4-" + (grid1.rowCount + 1)
            });
            if (store1.isDirty()) {

              store1.save({
                onComplete: onSave,
                onError: onSaveError
              });
            }
          }
        }, "addRow");
        //Deletion of Row
        var button1 = new Button({
          onClick: function() {
            var item = grid1.getItem(grid1.rowCount - 1);
            if (item == null) {
              return;
            }
            store1.deleteItem(item);

            if (store1.isDirty()) {
              store1.save({
                onComplete: onSave,
                onError: onSaveError
              });

            }
          }
        }, "delRow");
        var onSave = function() {
          // alert("Save done.");
        }
        var onSaveError = function(error) {
            alert("Error occurred: " + error)
          }
          // code for Multiple grids
        var grids = ["Hello", "Green", "World"];
        var arrayLength = grids.length;
        var Grids = [arrayLength];
        var divArr = [arrayLength];
        var data = [arrayLength];
        var store = [arrayLength];
        var layout = [arrayLength];
        var id = [arrayLength];
        var divName = "sam";
        var addR = [arrayLength];
        var delR = [arrayLength];
        var add = "addRow";
        var del = "delRow";
        for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
          dojo.place("<br><br><br>", dojo.body());
          layout[i] = [
            [{
              'name': 'No',
              'field': 'id',
              'width': '100px'
            }, {
              'name': 'Col Heading',
              'field': 'col2',
              'width': '150px',
              editable: true
            }, {
              'name': 'Col Heading',
              'field': 'col3',
              'width': '200px',
              editable: true
            }, {
              'name': 'Col Heading',
              'field': 'col4',
              'width': '150px',
              editable: true
            }]
          ];
          data[i] = {
            identifier: id,
            items: []
          };
          store[i] = new ItemFileWriteStore({
            data: data[i]
          });
          Grids[i] = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
            id: Grids[i],
            store: store[i],
            structure: layout[i],
            rowSelector: '20px',
            "style": "height:  100%; width: 100%"
          });

          divArr[i] = divName + i;
          addR[i] = divArr[i] + add + i;
          delR[i] = divArr[i] + del + i;
          dojo
            .place(
              "<div id='divArr[i]' style='width: 650px; height: 200px; border: 0px solid silver;'></div>",
              dojo.body());

          dojo.place("<br>", dojo.byId('divArr[i]'));
          Grids[i].placeAt(dojo.byId('divArr[i]'));
          Grids[i].startup();
          dojo.place("<br>", dojo.byId('divArr[i]'));
          //dojo.place("<button id= 'addR[i]','data-dojo-type='dijit.form.Button' onclick='myFunction()'>AddRow</button>", dojo.byId("divArr[i]"));
          //dojo.place("<button id= 'delR[i]', 'data-dojo-type='dijit.form.Button'>DelRow</button>",  dojo.byId("divArr[i]"));
          var button = new Button({
            label: 'Add',
            onClick: function(evt) {
              store[i].newItem({
                id: 'SL :',
                col2: 'col2-',
                col3: 'col3-',
                col4: 'col4-'
              });
              if (store[i].isDirty()) {
                store[i].save({
                  onComplete: onSave,
                  onError: onSaveError
                });
              }
            }
          });
          button.startup();
          button.placeAt('divArr[i]');
        }
      });
  </script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: oops! I think you forgot to paste your code.

Comment: Code copied, Copy paste the code and execute

Comment: It was javascript scoping issue. Place dynamic Grids and store in a global scope, the issue will be solved.